# How to print only value in a sql statement?

Tags: python, sql

SQL statement prints key as well as value, only want value

Trying to make a log in system, so have the code :

datapassword = conn.execute("SELECT Password From NewUsers WHERE Username = ?", [username_login]).fetchall()

but printing it gets me:

[{'Password': '1'}]

when i want it to just be '1'

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you get a `cursor` instance from the connection and then you use that to execute your query, so I am not sure which library you are using. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

```py
cursor = conn.cursor() # Get a cursor
# Execute query and fetch all the rows:
rows = cursor.select("SELECT Password From NewUsers WHERE Username = ?", [username_login]).fetchall()
# This returns presumably a list of dictionaries and so:
for row in rows:
    print(row['Password'])
```

Presumably, there is only a single row returned for a given user and so, better would be to use `fetchone`:

```py
cursor = conn.cursor() # Get a cursor
# Execute query and fetch a single row:
row = cursor.select("SELECT Password From NewUsers WHERE Username = ?", [username_login]).fetchone()
# This returned either a single row or None:
if row:
    print(row['Password']))
```